# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-flow

I have built my drools application using drools 6.2.0 .While running the application using Tomcat server(7.0) I am getting the following error:

```
    SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getRepository(KieServicesImpl.java:50)
    at BusinessLogic.BusinessLogic.display(BusinessLogic.java:42)
    at Webservice.service.display(service.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**

I have added all the jars required for drools 6.2.0 Even then I am getting the above mentioned error.

**

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue when running the Drools code in a web application (even though it worked as a standalone Drools project). 
I had added the necessary jars in Eclipse IDE however those were used during Compile time only and not available during Runtime thus a NoClassDefFound Error.
Please validate the jars are available in the lib folder in the WAR file for runtime execution.

Comment: Same problem It is running fine as standalone application problem is with web application

Comment: Can you verify if the jars are available inside the generated WAR file? Or added on the classpath of the web container?

Comment: Yes jar files are there in generated WAR file

Answer (score 1):

I had two copy of logging jar(slf4j-api-1.7.2) .One in Tomcat library folder and other in Drools application.Both jar files where same.I removed the logging jar file from drools application it resolved my issue.